# What exactly does Carnage mean by "Power Up"?

Tags: marvel, venom

In *Venom: Let There Be Carnage* (2021) @01:11:08, at the cathedral, Carnage and Venom are battling each other while Detective Mulligan uses a lift to reach the top.

Then, Carnage grasps the priest and commands him:

> Carnage: **Power up**.

What exactly does Carnage mean by "Power Up"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He's not commanding the priest to power up, he's referring to the priest *as a [power-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-up)*, e.g.

> an object that adds temporary benefits or extra abilities to the player character as a game mechanic.

When he eats the priest's brains, he'll be stronger than he was before.

[image: An animated gif showing Mario picking up a mushroom in Super Mario Bros. on NES, which is one of the most common examples of video game power-up trope.]